# Basic debugging with Java

Tags: java, debugging

I don't know how to fix these errors:

1. class or interface expected errors
2. package doesn't exists
3. cannot find symbol
4. illegal start of type
5. cannot access java.lang

How can I better understand where the problems in my code are occurring?  How can I debug these issues?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ResourcesTesterApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = readLineWithResources();
        String s2 = readLineWithFinally();
    }

    public static String readLineWithResources() {
        System.out.println("Starting readLineWithResources method.");

        try (RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("products.ran", "r")) {
            return in.readLine();   
        }} catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static String readLineWithFinally() {
        System.out.println("Starting readLineWithFinally method.");
        RandomAccessFile in = null;
        String s = null;

        try {
            in = new RandomAccessFile("products.ran", "r");
            s = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    System.out.println("RandomAccessFile closed");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("RandomAccessFile " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: The problem you have isn't fixing errors... it's finding them and narrowing down your problem to begin with.  I suggest taking your code apart piece by piece to narrow things down, if the output from your debugger isn't helpful to you.  When you have a single question with the code that reproduces it, try posting back here.  Otherwise, I'm afraid this question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow.  Please see the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: What lines are throwing these errors?  Also, try to format your code so that it's readable.  Left-side spacing and lining up brackets is very important.

Comment: Hi Emily.  The reason you are receiving down votes on this question is because you haven't shown any indication that you have tried to solve the problem yourself.  In the future, you should indicate what specifically your problem is, what you've tried to fix it, and what you think is wrong.  In this way, it will seem like you want to acquire knowledge rather than just have someone fix your program for you. =)  There are other forums out there for more *gimme the codez!* kind of requests.

Comment: According to the errors, it seem like this is copied off some other place and you are running into issues just trying to run them. If so, did the place you copied from provide step-by-step tutorial and you followed them all?

Comment: @Carth, The other question is not a duplicate.  It just references the same code.

Comment: Thanks brad. Sorry guys but i cant fix it. I tried lot of things. I am confused about spacing now. How do you space the curly brackets?

Comment: I would use an IDE. It will make it easier to a) write code which compiles and help you correct errors b) suggest ways to improve your code and fixed it c) format your code d) run you code e) debug your code.

Comment: @EmilyMyers, If you are not using an IDE currently, check out Eclipse.  http://www.eclipse.org/  It's free, and is a decent IDE for Java projects.

Comment: I am using IDE. But i am now confused about how to do spacing for curly brackets coz someone mentioned it depends on it.

Comment: @EmilyMyers, The compiler doesn't care about your braces, but since these problems aren't in your compiler and are in the human element of programming, you should fix them.  See this article:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style  I personally use "1TBS", but as you can see, there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You question is how to better understand and debug these errors.  Well all I can say is, look at the actual error message output, it will normally include a line number.  Now you can look at the specific line of code and see if you can spot what is wrong.

I don't know if the formatting of the code in your question comes from a failed attempt at pasting it into stackoverflow.com or if that is also how you are working with it, but you should format it properly and that will help with spotting problems.  For example, when I formatted your code above straight away you can see an additional closing curly brace.

Once you have the actual error messages and line numbers etc. your best bet is to google the error and try to understand what it means.  Once you have exhausted that avenue come back here and formulate a specific question showing exactly what the error message is and the code you are running.  Avoid grouping many problems into one question like you have done here.

Answer (score 1):

1. this usually means you are writing code outside of a method.
2. this simply means you referenced a package that the java compiler cannot find.
3. this means you wrote a nonexistant variable.
4. this usually means you did not complete a statement, and you started writing the next one.
5. I dont know about this one, maybe be more specific?

I strongly suggest you take a look at the java tutorials, and follow their examples.
you can find them at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/